# c# nameof original parameter is being overwritten

Tags: c#

I am trying to make checking for null exceptions easier, so I created this static method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Static method for throwing multiple argument null exceptions
/// </summary>
/// <param name="arguments">An array of arguments</param>
public static void ArgumentIsNull(params object[] arguments)
{

    // For each argument, if the argument is null, throw an error
    foreach (var argument in arguments)
        if (argument == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(String.Format(Resources.ArgumentNullException, nameof(argument)));
}
```

The problem is, my error looks like this:

> You're missing the required parameter: argument

I know this is because of the parameter name I am looping through

```
var argument in arguments
```

What I would like to do is get the name of the argument that was passed.
For example, here is a call to this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Default constructor
/// </summary>
/// <param name="unitOfWork"></param>
/// <param name="service"></param>
/// <param name="apiKey"></param>
public SendGridProvider(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, EmailService service, string apiKey) 
    : base(apiKey, "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/")
{

    // Throw an error if our key is not provided
    ThrowIf.ArgumentIsNull(unitOfWork, service, apiKey);

    // Assign our fields
    this.apiKey = apiKey;
    this.service = service;
    this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

so if the **unitOfWork** is null, I would like the error to be

> You're missing the required parameter: unitOfWork

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're comparing chalk and cheese. `nameof(unitOfWork)` will have a name because that parameter has that name. `arguments` will always just be arguments

Comment: Replace your method with one that only checks a single argument or pass `KeyValuePair<string, object>` for every argument..

Comment: tried that, same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void ThrowIfNull<T>(params Expression<Func<T>>[] exprs)
{
    foreach(var expr in exprs)
    {
        var member = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
        var name = member.Member.Name;
        var value = expr.Compile()();
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't directly possible owing to nameof just getting the name of the variable, but you can always abuse expressions!

Calling it would look like:

```
public void DoSomething(string x, string y)
{
    Ext.ThrowIfNull(() => x, () => y);
}
```

Bear in mind, having a typed method will restrict calling it to using expressions sharing the same generic type (or common subtype / interface).

Just drop the generic type and use `object`, to support different typed expressions:

```
void ThrowIfNull(params Expression<Func<object>>[] exprs)
```

Comment: can that be done for multiple parameters (without knowing how many)? like `public void DoSomething(string x, string y) { Ext.ThrowIfNull(() => x, () => y); }`

Comment: @r3plica and of course you can jiggle it around any way you please, for example you could have a single expression if any of them are null with the parameter name and message built from the ones that *are* null - could do all sorts with it!

Comment: looks good, I will have a look at this and mark it as the answer if it works :D

Comment: I get an error when invoking this method: The type arguments for method 'ThrowIf.ArgumentIsNull<T>(params Expression<Func<T>>[])' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: What does your call to the method look like? You may need to do `ArgumentIsNull<ArgTypeHere>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112518/discussion-between-clint-and-r3plica).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no reliable way to do that (unless you use some custom post compile code weaving tool). `nameof(` is resolved at compile time and the passed in variables are set at run time.

In a optimized build the local variables don't even have their original variable names anywhere in the compiled IL code.

Here is a example of a [Fody extension](https://github.com/NickStrupat/NameOf) that does basic NameOf functionality via code weaving, perhaps you could extend what it does to have it look at what is being passed in and pass along a `string[]` to grab the parameter names.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to get into code weaving, and wanted a utility method to allow easy exception throwing while still providing enough detail that you could troubleshoot your errors, you could pass the parameters over as a `Dictionary<string, object>` (or a `Tuple` I suppose) instead of using the params keyword and passing an array.

```
ThrowIf.ArgumentIsNull(new Dictionary<string, object>() 
{
    {nameof(unitofwork), unitOfWork}, 
    {nameof(service), service}
});
```

It is, admittedly, not as sexy as just passing over a list of parameters.  It will however meet your requirements.

Comment: I also thought of this. The major drawback is that you always have to initialize this dictionary everywhere. You cannot build a method that does this for you. That's why i'd prefer to pass only a single argument.

Comment: I also managed to do that, but like Tim said, it wasn't great having to initialize the dictionary every time I want to throw a potential error